# Circle bisecting circumference of another circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

The circle $x^2 + y^2 +2gx +2fy +c=0$ bisects the circumference of the circle $x^2 + y^2 +2ax +2by +d=0$. Then:

A) $2a(g-a) +2b(f-b)=c-d$

B) $2g(g-a) +2f(f-b)=d-c$

C) $2a(g+a) +2b(f+b)=c+d$

D) $2g(g+a) +2f(f+b)=c+d$

Comment: any thoughts for this question?

Comment: I am not able to figure out an approach for the question, except that we can consider (h1,k1) and (h2,k2) to be the points of intersection of the circumferences

Comment: @Bhavya - How about considering the common chord of the circle $C_1\equiv x^2 + y^2 +2gx +2fy +c=0$ and $C_2\equiv x^2 + y^2 +2ax +2by +d=0$ to be the diameter of $C_2$

Comment: @user350331 sorry.  I dont know the concept of common chord. Could you just explain it to me in brief. Thanks 

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a guide for basic latex tutorial, it is really easy since the syntax is kind of intuitive. So go through it.

Comment: You might wanna read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/i-have-been-banned-from-asking-questions-what-should-i-do/24784#24784) meta post for you not being able to ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two circles $$C_1\equiv x^2 + y^2 +2gx +2fy +c=0$$ $$\&$$ $$C_2\equiv x^2 + y^2 +2ax +2by +d=0$$ as shown in the figure below

[image]

As the common chord passes through $(x_1,y_1)\; \& \;(x_2,y_2)$, so it will satisfy both the circles $C_1$ and $C_2$, so on solving both the equations that you get when you put both the point of intersections into the equation of both the circles, you will end up with

$$2(g-a)x_1 + 2 (f-b)y_1 + c-d =0\tag{1}$$
$$2(g-a)x_2 + 2 (f-b)y_2 + c-d =0\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can conclude that the equation of common chord is $$\ell_{cc}\equiv 2(g-a)x+2(f-b)y+c-d =0$$

Now, lets turn to your question, since $C_1$ bisects $C_2$ (which means that the circumference of the circle is divided into two equal parts), so the common chord of both the circles should be the diameter of $C_2$. As, the diameter is a chord that passes through the center of the circle, hence $\ell_{cc}$ also passes through the center of $C_2$, i.e. $(a,b)$.

So, the answer is $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{2(g-a)a+2(f-b)b=d-c}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, I am new to the site, and don't know much about how it works, and right now I am not able to post a question. Can u plz help me. I don't know if this is the correct place or all, so sorry about that. Plz help me, or redirect me . Thanks a lot

Comment: First of all this site has most probably all the questions answered that you might be thinking of posting. So, all you have to do is search in the search bar at the top right corner of the site's page(telling from my own experience). And one more thing though I posted my answer to your question, it is important to note that you presented it in a very poor manner. It is very important that you show your thought process that you had while trying to come up with a solution and for that you must ponder for a while.

Comment: Yeah. I'll have to keep that in mind. But is this ban temporary, or do I have to do somethin else about it. Plz help. Thanks 

Comment: I just posted my answer so that you don't get demotivated on posting your concerns regarding a question, just that you understand that people try to put only that much effort that the person posting the post has shown, so if you elaborately state your thought process you might recieve some invaluable advice from people posting their answers. For improving the quality of your posts you might wanna refer to the FAQ of MSE. And as you are new to the community do note that MSE is the most liberal communities of all the stack exchange site(at least of those in which I am).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. You've been of great help. Thanks again 

Comment: Oh yeah I just forgot about it,  well that never happened with me, so I don't know what must have happened, but I think it might have been due to the close votes(votes that favor closing a question due to some reasons), you might wanna check the FAQs, and do learn some latex editing, and read some FAQs, though it might take some time, but when you become well versed with some basic rules here you will see that it gets easier from then.